# Merging attributes in QGIS?

Tags: merge, qgis-3

I have a layer with several polygons making up a division together. They all have attributes with population.

Is it possible to add up the population in a merge so I don't have to use a calculator every time the data is updated?

Comment: What do you mean by division? How often is your data updated? I assume you want to automate this? Or is manually repeating several steps in QGIS ok?

Answer (score 3):

An easy way to add or sum numbers is using sql in a virtual layer in QGIS.

Sum all numbers in mycolumn:

```
select sum(mycolumn) from mytable
```

Sum all numbers in mycolumn1 based on another column:

```
select sum(mycolumn1), mycolumn2 from mytable group by mycolumn2
```

Update:

You can also create a new geometry based off a value from another column:

```
select sum(mycolumn1), mycolumn2, st_union(geometry) as geometry 
from mytable group by mycolumn2
```

You can find the Virtual Layer  editor in the Data Source Manager.

Comment: I think it's  possible to add the geometry column to the query and get a merged polygon with the summed value in attribute table, do you have an exemple query with that ?

Comment: Updated the answer merging geometries together that have the same value in column mycolumn2

Answer (score 2):

**QGIS 3.0+**

I like `Virtual Layer` approach, but currently having a trouble using it in QGIS 3.0-3.2 for some unknown reasons. Just in case you also have issue with Virtual Layer, I would suggest **Aggregate** function.

You can find it in `Processing Toolbox | Vector geometry | Aggregate`.

[image]

1. Put the field you want (in my example it is `val` field) into the `Input expression` list.
2. Select **sum** in the `Aggregate function`.
3. Select **Integer** in the `Type` (as your data is *population*)
4. Run the tool

[image]

Please note the output geometries are multi-part objects.